# php script to display data from SQL database

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a database on phpmyadmin and I want to display some data (not all the data) from a table into a table on HTML/PHP. I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. Each table row must have 3 cells. That is why I used the $nrArt variable in the php script. Can you help?

```
<table class="art-content">
    <div class="row">
    <? php
       try {$cnx= new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=restaurant","root", "");
     $interogare=$cnx -> prepare("SELECT id_preparat, nume, pret, foto from preparate WHERE id_categorie= 1");
     $interogare -> execute();
     $nrArt = 0;
     foreach ($interogare-> fetchAll() as $linie){
        $id=$linie["id_preparat"];
        $nume=$linie["nume"];
        $pret=$linie["pret"];
        $img=$linie["foto"];
        if($nrArt==0){
            echo '<tr class="col-1-3">';
             }
        echo '<div class="wrap-col">';
        echo '<td class="item-container">';
        echo'<a class="example-image-link" href="images/'.$img.'" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="'.$nume.'">';
        echo '<div class="item-caption">';
            echo '<div class="item-caption-inner">';
                echo'<div class="item-caption-inner1">';
                        echo'<h3>Pret</h3>';
                        echo '<span>'.$pret.'RON</span>';
                        echo'</div>';
                echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '<img class="example-image" src="images/'.$img.'" alt=""/>';
    echo'</a>';                     
    echo '</td>';
    $nrArt++;
    if($nrArt>2){
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
}
    catch (PDOException $e){
    die("Conectare imposibila: ". $e -> getMessage()); }
     ?>
    </div>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset your variable so

not:

```
if($nrArt>2){
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
```

but:

```
if($nrArt>2){
        echo '</tr>';
$nrArt = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I reseted it, but the script still doesn't work. :(

Comment: Your another problem is that you mix DIV with TABLE and TD. In TABLE you cannot put DIV like that. See in HTML documentation what looks correct TABLE TR TD syntax

Comment: You need to choose if you want to use TABLE or DIV to create your layout